# Trying to mount a folder from school's network

Tags: linux, mount

This is what I'm told to do...

```
mount -t smbfs -o username=USERNAME,port=9900 \ //localhost/USERNAME /YOUR_LOCAL_MOUNT_POINT
```

I'm new to Linux so I'm sure I'm not doing this right but I can't figure out what the right syntax is for the last part.  I tried...

```
/home/andyd/documents/school
```

for `/YOUR_LOCAL_MOUNT_POINT`

that didn't work

Comment: Do you have an empty folder named `/home/andyd/documents/school`?  What errors do you see when you run the command (please update your post with that info)?  The first problem seems like if you are actually using `//localhost/username` then you will be trying to mount a share from your localhost (the machine that you are using).

Comment: Hey so I figured out that format for location was wrong but not now it looks like smbfs is the issue.  Apparently that has been deprecated in favor cifs but I need to use smbfs.  I'll have a look on what I can do about getting it installed. Thanks for the help!